# AzureSigningError for Azure blob

Tags: azure

I have a python app running as Azure function, which read the secrets from Azure Vault to access blob storage, it works fine on my local, but when it running in Azure function, it fails with this exception:

Exception: AzureSigningError: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (109) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

This stack looks like this:

```
'Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 312, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 431, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/myfunction/__init__.py", line 5, in main
    projectMacro.fromFh(blobin)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/myfunction/operation.py", line 13, in fromFh
    data = readData(fh.name)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/core/communication/__init__.py", line 39, in readData
    return getFsClient().read(**getBlobandContainerName(fh))
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/core/communication/base_client.py", line 76, in read
    return self._read(**b)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/core/communication/fs_client.py", line 23, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/core/communication/fs_client.py", line 44, in _read
    return self._client.get_blob_to_text(container, blob)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 2488, in get_blob_to_text
    cpk=cpk)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 2369, in get_blob_to_bytes
    cpk=cpk)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 2160, in get_blob_to_stream
    cpk=cpk)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 1887, in _get_blob
    operation_context=_context)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 402, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 374, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 314, in _perform_request
    self.authentication.sign_request(request)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/common/_auth.py", line 92, in sign_request
    self._add_authorization_header(request, string_to_sign)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/storage/common/_auth.py", line 75, in _add_authorization_header
    raise _wrap_exception(ex, AzureSigningError)'
```

Looks like some signature issue when trying to read from blob? Based on my function log, the function did connect to blob account successfully.

Any lead here would be truly appreciated.

Comment: the obvious question would be - how does your function connect to the key vault? did you give it credentials\identity to work when its deployed in the cloud?